# WPF - Do not show Context menu when ListView is empty

Tags: wpf, listview, binding, contextmenu, visibility

I have a ContextMenu bind to ListView, but I don't want to be the menu shown when the ListView is empty. I tried direct binding to element, tried binding using FindAncestor, but none of these works and the menu is always shown when I click right mouse button in the ListView.
What would be the correct binding?

```
<Grid>
<ListView x:Name="loginListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Logins}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Login" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Login}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Password" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Password}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>

    <ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem 
                Header="Delete login" 
                Visibility="{Binding ElementName=loginListView, Path=Items.Count, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.ContextMenu>
</ListView>
```

```
public class visibilityConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((int)value > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }                
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [ContextMenuService.IsEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenuservice.isenabled.aspx) property to prevent the ContextMenu from being shown.  Something like:

```
<ListView x:Name="loginListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Logins}"
    ContextMenuService.IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=loginListView,
        Path=Items.Count, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
```

using the converter that returns True or False.

Since the binding is now on the ListView itself, you could also use a Binding with a RelativeSource of Self instead of having to use ElementName, or you could bind directly to the DataContext by setting the path to `Logins.Count` (assuming Logins has its own Count property).

Comment: Accepted as an answer, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to listen to the ListView's ContextMenuOpening event. You can then perform whatever logic you want and cancel the menu from opening.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know it can be done in code, but I wanted to have it done exactly in the XAML using Binding.

Answer (score 0):

Your binding wont work.
The Visibility property is not a boolean, it's an enum.  you should use the built-in converter `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, sorry my fault, I copied wrong converter from clipboard here. 
I had it returning return Visibility.Visible or Visibility.Hidden, but it didn't solve my problem.

Strange is that when I do this:

```
<ListView.ContextMenu>
   <ContextMenu>
      <MenuItem Header="{Binding ElementName=loginListView, Path=Items.Count}"/>
   </ContextMenu>
</ListView.ContextMenu>
```

I get a ContextMenu with empty string, regardless the ListView has items or not!
But in the same form when I do this:

```
<Button Content="{Binding ElementName=loginListView, Path=Items.Count}" Name="deleteButton" Width="100" Height="30" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
```

I see the button content changes correctly according to ListView items count! It seems that ListView has to have other binding, FindAncestor with AncestorType=ListView didn't work as well and I'm out of ideas :-(